# What is the Laplace transform of $\exp(a\times t^n)$?

Tags: exponential-function, laplace-transform, closed-form, moment-generating-functions

Is there a closed form expression for the Laplace transform of $\exp(a \times t^n)$ for constant $a \in \rm R$ and integers $n > 2$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: For general `n` probably not exist. For `n=3,4,5,6....` solution by generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: Looks like: $\mathcal{L}_t\left[\exp \left(a t^n\right)\right](s)=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{j-\frac{1+j}{n}} a^{-\frac{1+j}{n}} s^j \Gamma \left(\frac{1+j}{n}\right)}{n \Gamma (1+j)}$ but no closed-form.